# How to add Google events tracking code to CTA button on popup?

Tags: events, google-analytics, wordpress, tracking

I have installed a pop-up plugin on my Wordpress site. The pop-up has a CTA button that links to an inner page and I would like to track clicks on the button using Google events tracking.

This is the Google analytics code I'm using: `onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Popup', 'click']);"`

and the following code is from the plugin which outputs the CTA button link:

```
if ( $has_cta ) {
        $cta_button_tag = sprintf(
            '<a href="%1$s" class="wdpu-cta" target="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( $this->cta_link ),
            esc_attr( $cta_target ),
            esc_html( $this->cta_label )
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I strongly recommend you upgrade your tracking to Google universal analytics (you're currently still on ga.js classic)

Just add your onclick event to the a element then:

```
if ( $has_cta ) {
        $cta_button_tag = sprintf(
            '<a href="%1$s" class="wdpu-cta" target="%2$s" onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Popup\', \'click\']);">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( $this->cta_link ),
            esc_attr( $cta_target ),
            esc_html( $this->cta_label )
        );
```

This will certainly fire off the tracking but it may be cancelled by the browser.  You therefore need to investigate the hitCallback feature of GA.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting the following error when loading the site admin page: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in...` Also, I read somewhere that I might need to add a line to the Google analytics tracking  code in the header file?

Comment: @user2205555, you need to escape ' with \ in code above.

Comment: @Alex good spot, i've ammended the code in my reply.  thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm now using the universal analytics code. Do I need to edit the main Google analytics script in the header file?